# Fantasy movie with a side protagonist who can turn to stone at will but is smashed by the villain

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched it when I was younger, it was a kids' movie (saw it sometime in the late 2000's or early 2010's). The main protagonist's friend or ally of some sort could turn to stone when he wanted to. However the antagonist killed him by smashing his stone form. That's about all I remember.

Comment: Live action or animated?  If the latter, what style?  Could the kid move in stone form?  How did the antagonist smash him? (with a giant mallet? an anvil?)

Comment: Can't remember, only the trauma...

Comment: Kid couldn't move in stone form, I don't think.

Comment: The relevant trope is [Literally Shattered Lives](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LiterallyShatteredLives) which you might look through to see if you find a match.